# d3 filter the return function value force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can i filter the return function based on the condition:
For example my json datas for link

```
"links": [
        {
            "pie": "false",
            "source": 1,
            "target": 0
        },
        {
            "pie": "true",
            "source": 2,
            "target": 1
        },
        {
            "pie": "true",
            "source": 3,
            "target": 1
        },
        {
            "pie": "false",
            "source": 4,
            "target": 2
        },
        {
            "pie": "true",
            "source": 4,
            "target": 3
        }
    ]
```

so based upon the pie "TRUE" or "FALSE" i have to append marker on the link.
CODE:

```
var path =  d3.select('.pitch').selectAll("path")
                    .data(force.links())
                  .enter().append("svg:path")
                //    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("marker-end",function(d){ if(d.pie) return "url(#BLUE)"});// condition
```

But it doesnt work for me. Please help me out. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have edited the code as                                              path.filter(function(d){return d.arrow == true;}).attr("marker-end",function(d){ return "url(#BLUE)"}).attr("stroke-linecap", "round"); working FINE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nodes.filter(function(d){return d.pie === 'true'};
```

Something along those lines i think will work